# Create a Web Deployment Package using Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, web-applications, web-deployment

Is there a way to create a Web Deployment Package using Powershell for a Visual Studios C# Web Application? I know how to create the package directly in Visual Studios, but I'm trying to automate this process by using Powershell scripts that can be triggered in TeamCity.

Comment: Have you met [this](http://alsagile.com/post/70283855921/deploying-to-iis-using-msdeploy-from-powershell) post?

Comment: That doesn't describe how to create a package, only how to deploy one